# input text size attribute not working IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, input

I have an html page dynamically generated by javascript with the onLoad event. 
This is the javascript:

```
function populateTable(q,a1,a2,a3,a4) {
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        table = document.createElement("table");
        table.appendChild(createQuestion(q,i));
        for (var j=0;j<4;j++) {
            var answer= eval("a" + (j+1));
            table.appendChild(createAnswers(j,answer,i));
        }
        var tabform= document.getElementById("tablesform");
        tabform.appendChild(table);
    }
}

function createQuestion(quest,i) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var tabd = document.createElement("td");
    tabd.setAttribute("class","question");
    var qinput=document.createElement("input");
    qinput.setAttribute("type","text");
    qinput.setAttribute("name","q" + (i+1));
    qinput.setAttribute("value",quest[i]);
    qinput.setAttribute("readonly","readonly");
    qinput.setAttribute("size","50"); 
    row.appendChild(qinput);
    var tabd1 = document.createElement("td");
    var rdiv = document.createElement("div");
    rdiv.setAttribute("id","result" + (i+1));
    tabd1.appendChild(rdiv);
    row.appendChild(tabd1);

    return row;
}
```

in FF it works fine, it makes 10 neat tables, each with the question inside the text input on the first row, with all of the text input fields of the same size (50), etc etc..

on IE8 the text field remains empty, and moreover its size is not fixed! The strange thing is that if I go look at the html that was generated i see:

```
<FORM id=tablesform method=post action=processquiz.php>
    <INPUT value=" - Correct The Test - " type=submit>
    <INPUT onclick="window.location='logout.php'" value=" - Log Out -  " type=button> 
    <TABLE>
        <TR>
            <INPUT value="What browser has the most DHTML extentions?" readOnly size=50 type=text name=q1>
            <TD><DIV id=result1></DIV></TD>
        </TR>
```

which is perfectly fine! What could be the problem?

EDIT: document is html 4.01 strict

Comment: You should avoid `eval()`!

Comment: What is your doctype?

Comment: DOCTYPE is a strong contender for being the cause of problems like this. But in any case, you should use CSS to define your layout, not those old-style deprecated attributes.

Comment: so like use input { width:50px; } ?

Comment: @DerekHenderson did not know eval was deprecated. what could I use in my case instead? Don't see other ways, the variable has to be dynamic..

Comment: @AlexButera `eval()` is not deprecated, but it's a bad idea to use. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: `eval` isn't deprecated, it's just poor practice. In this case, better practice would be to pass the `a1`,`a2`, etc vars into the function as an array or object, then you could refer to `a[1]` etc without needing any `eval` calls.

Comment: Re CSS: yes, exactly like that. The `size` attribute is deprecated; CSS like `{width:50px;}` is the modern preferred alternative. Additionally, be aware that using tables for layout as you're doing is also deprecated. Again, modern CSS techniques are considered better practice. (not to mention the fact that your table code is actually invalid HTML anyway, since the input is not inside a `<td>` element; that's probably the real reason the `size` attribute is playing up)

Comment: @AlexButera, nobody said `.eval()` is deprecated, just that you shouldn't use it.  In your case, you don't need it because you can just step through `arguments`.  Change `for (var j=0;j<4;j++) {` to `for (var j = 1; j < arguments.length; j += 1) {`. Then replace the next two lines with `var answer = arguments[j];` and `table.appendChild(createAnswers(j - 1, answer, i));`. Moral of the story is there is always a better way than to use `.eval()`.

Comment: I have tried your code with an HTML 4.0 strict doctype, and I cannot replicate this bug at all. Sry.  My only suggestion is that perhaps something else on the page that you haven't shown us, perhaps an IE conditional stylesheet, is causing this problem.